# Move every folder that is two levels down up one level

Tags: database, batch-file

I'm trying to undo a TERRIBLE design decision I was forced to implement in a database, and hope there's a batch file that can fix this.

Currently files for records are stored by the name field, and then by the record number. My last boss insisted on being able to brose the records through windows instead of the records interface. I need to fix this, because I need to be able to create records without a name field.

So here's the current structure

```
 Recordfiles
  John Smith
   230
    approvedpacket.pdf
    initialpacket.pdf
   232
    Approved packet.pdf
    Initialpacket.pdf
  Jane Frank
   343
    Deniedpacket.pdf
```

What I need is for it to look like

```
 Recordfiles
  230
  232
  343
```

So I need to move every folder and its contents that is two levels down from /recordfiles/ up one level. I've tried a lot of batch file solutions from various sites, but no luck so far. Each just pops up the command window for a moment and nothing else.

Of note: I'm very new at this, I just know some very entry-level visual basic and have no formal training. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Okay so... I found a way to do this. I went to /recordfiles/, did a * search, waited it for it to load every single file in those folders, selected all the numbered folders, and copy/pasted them to where I wanted them to be. So there's no rush on this, but I am currious how I could do this with a batch file for future projects.

Comment: What have you tried? Please share your efforts! Do the level-one folders need to be removed?

Comment: What to do in case of conflicts, e. g., when both directories `John Smith` and `Jane Frank` contain a sub-directory `230`?

Answer (score 0):

```
> tree /F
A:.
│   _.cmd
│
└───Recordfiles
    ├───Jane Frank
    │   └───343
    │           Deniedpacket.pdf
    │
    └───John Smith
        ├───230
        │       approvedpacket.pdf
        │       initialpacket.pdf
        │
        └───232
                Approved packet.pdf
                Initialpacket.pdf
```

This one line does the move

```
> for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /B/S/AD "???" ^|findstr "\\[0-9][0-9][0-9]$" ') do @Move "%A" "%A\..\.."
```

In a batch file double the percent signs

```
@Echo off
CD /D "X:\path\Recordfiles"
for /f "delims=" %%A in (
    'dir /B/S/AD "???" ^|findstr "\\[0-9][0-9][0-9]$" '
) do Move "%%A" "%%A\..\.."
```

---

```
> tree /F
Auflistung der Ordnerpfade für Volume RamDisk
Volumeseriennummer : 5566-7788
A:.
│   _.cmd
│
└───Recordfiles
    ├───230
    │       approvedpacket.pdf
    │       initialpacket.pdf
    │
    ├───232
    │       Approved packet.pdf
    │       Initialpacket.pdf
    │
    ├───343
    │       Deniedpacket.pdf
    │
    ├───Jane Frank
    └───John Smith
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this (untested):

```cmd
pushd "D:\path\to\RecordFiles" || exit /B 1
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%A in ('dir /B /A:D "*"') do (
    for /D %%B in ("%%~A\*") do (
        move /Y "%%~B" "%%~dpA%%~nxB"
    )
    rmdir "%%~A"
)
popd
```